# Android Webview can not redirect to a website directly and via getElementById().click()

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect, webview

I'm facing a problem about http redirection. A website that I need to redirect to doesn't allow me to redirect to it. I have to use `javascript:getElementById('someid').click()`to redirect to it.

The problem is it only works with Web Browser, in Android webview it doesn't work with javascript code such as
`javascript:getElementById('someid').click()`

I don't know why, can anyone please explain and help me out.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Javascript, you will need to do something along these lines instead of `getElementById('someid').click()`

`window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Answer (score 0):

You must enable javascript in webview, by default as I know it's off ))

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by default. You should enable JavaScript for working with.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I already setJavaScriptEnabled true. The problem is webview redirected but the target website detected that is automatic click, not user click then show me the error message. Javascript click() method works on web browser but not webview.